# Add check all to js script

Tags: checkbox, mailto

I would like to add "check all" and "uncheck all" button to this script. My js coding skills isnt too good and any help would be highly appricated.

See working example jsfiddle here: [http://jsfiddle.net/Efz72/38/]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to add a button that calls the following jQuery function:

```
function checkAllCheckboxes(){
   $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', true) 
}
```

The HTML code for the button should look something like:

```
 <input type="button" value="Check All" onclick="checkAllCheckboxes();" />
```

Two notes:
 1. The `<input>` tags in your code does not have a closing bracket ( `/>` )
 2. You want the checkAllCheckboxes function above to be defined as '`No wrap - in <head>`' in JSFiddle for this to work properly there.

Comment: Thank you! Think i got it working. How can i uncheck?

Comment: If this help you, please help me by marking the answer as accepted :) (clicking the empty check mark).

Comment: to uncheck the checkboxes, just change the 'true' to 'false'. You can pass that as a parameter to the function to avoid code duplication.

Comment: Figured it out by changing the "true" to "false", seem to work here now: http://jsfiddle.net/Efz72/58/